Can KDEnlive actually crop a video area, like we crop an image?
OBS screen recording filled non-selected area black (that is, the video resolution was 1080p like the monitor, even though I had selected only part of the monitor). I wanted to "crop" it to the actual video area using Kdenlive. A.I. told me to use Edge Crop, but I could not get what I want. In the end, I just used ffmpeg -i proj1.mp4 -filter:v "crop=800:500:0:0" output.mp4 command-line.
Can I get the same result with Kdenlive? Note that the video had two segments (I added a cut in the middle so that I could apply "blur" to only a part of timeline.

Yes of course - use a Transform Effect. If your recorded area was actually 800x500, then the aspect ratio will not match 1920x1080. You could resize the 1920x1080 frame by 1920/800 width and 1080/500 height to get the small video zoomed in, or use 2.4x size if you're fine with top and part being cropped out.
